# Homework-Prove Big omega with witness

Tags: big-o, gomega

I am having trouble solving a proof. Given the situations : f(x)=x^4-50x^3+1 g(x)=x^4 we need to show that f(x)is big omega of g(x), also need to provide the witness

Comment: You definitely need to narrow down this question to describe what, specifically, you're having trouble with. Please read the following: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Unrelated, but gomega is something completely different.